# Cannot move the icons in windows explorer

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-icons

I cannot move items in any explorer instance. Desktop or any other Explorer folder, I just can't move icons around.

I've tried anti virus / anti-spyware software. I have SP3 and it's not due to "keep icons aligned" settings.

Any ideas?